# importing an external image on top of a node using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-graphs

How can I generate this nodes and edge structure using tikz in latex?  [image]

I created the following figure using `tikz`, now I'd like to put some figures on the top of each node (e.g. a heart with heart-beat in one and a cheese figure on the other node)?

The reason I want to create the heart figure using `tikz` is that the quality of my external image reduces because I cropped heart-rate from one image put it on the top of heart figure and resizing it constantly decreases its quality.

I also would like to put one of the characters from this package `\usepackage{tikzlings}` as a figure on top of the other node and it doesn't work (for instance `\thing[cheese]`) or even not use this package but either another package or just create a cheese figure inside the node).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,cal,positioning}
\usepackage{tikzlings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     %nodes for latent state
        \node[scale=0.07,circle, fill=red!40!brown!65] (P1) at (0,7) {\includegraphics[]{}};
        \node[scale=0.07,circle, fill=red!40!brown!65] (P2) at (2.5,7) {\includegraphics[]{}};
        \node[align=center] at (0,6.2){\tiny\textbf{\textsc{Low}}};
        \node[align=center] at (2.5,6.2){\tiny\textbf{\textsc{High}}};
        %links
        \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (P2) edge [bend right] coordinate [pos=0.2] (top) (P1) 
    (P1) edge [bend right] (P2)
    ;
    \path (P1) edge [loop left] node {} (P1);
    \path (P2) edge [loop right] node {} (P2);
    %%%%%%%%%%
    %%% RECTANGLES %%%
\node[draw, thick, dotted, rounded corners, inner xsep=3.5em, inner ysep=1em, fit=(P1) (P2)] (box) {};
\node[fill=white] at (box.south) {\tiny\textbf{\textsc{States}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello ! I am afraid I do not fully understand your question. The first image can be obtained using some `bend left`,`bend right` and `loop left`,`loop right`. But I can't figure the link with the heart. Can you provide a MWE so we have something to start from ?

Comment: @BambOo I managed to make my total graph structure with nodes and links but have problems to put images on the nodes.

Comment: Sorry but your example is not complete. It lacks `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: @BambOo I updated my question and its code.

Comment: the code needs to load some libraries!!! fit command!!

Comment: I was about to say that too. You should add `\usetikzlibrary{fit}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, based on your code, I obtain the following picture:

[image]

Based on your intent to use an image clipped by a path, I propose you an alternative based on the `path picture` syntax presented in section §15.6 of the `pgfmanual`. This alternative gives the figure at the bottom of this answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\tikzset{
    img/.style={circle, fill=red!40!brown!65,inner sep=0pt},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %nodes for latent state
    % Current code
    %\node[img] (P1) at (0,7) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}};
    %\node[img] (P2) at (2.5,7) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}};
    % Proposal
    \path[img] (0,7) circle (5mm) [path picture={\node (P1) at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}};}] ;
    \path[img] (2.5,7) circle (5mm) [path picture={\node (P2) at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}};}] ;
    \node[align=center] at (0,6.2){\tiny\textbf{\textsc{Low}}};
    \node[align=center] at (2.5,6.2){\tiny\textbf{\textsc{High}}};
    %links
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (P2) edge [bend right] coordinate [pos=0.2] (top) (P1)
    (P1) edge [bend right] (P2)
    ;
    \path (P1) edge [loop left] node {} (P1);
    \path (P2) edge [loop right] node {} (P2);
    %%%%%%%%%%
    %%% RECTANGLES %%%
    \node[draw, thick, dotted, rounded corners, inner xsep=3.5em, inner ysep=1em, fit=(P1) (P2)] (box) {};
    \node[fill=white] at (box.south) {\tiny\textbf{\textsc{States}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is working version including an improved definition of the "Low" and "High" node position with the `positioning` library and the inclusion of the `\tikzlings` in the nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\tikzset{
    img/.style={circle, fill=red!40!brown!65,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %nodes for latent state
    \path[img] (0,7) circle (5mm) [path picture={\node (P1) at (path picture bounding box.center) {\tikz[scale=0.5]{\marmot}};}] ;
    \path[img] (2.5,7) circle (5mm) [path picture={\node (P2) at (path picture bounding box.center) {\tikz[scale=0.5]{\cat}};}] ;
    \node[below=5mm of P1.center] (P1l) {\tiny\textbf{\textsc{Low}}};
    \node[below=5mm of P2.center] (P2l) {\tiny\textbf{\textsc{High}}};
    %links
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (P2) edge [bend right] coordinate [pos=0.2] (top) (P1)
    (P1) edge [bend right] (P2)
    ;
    \path (P1) edge [loop left] node {} (P1);
    \path (P2) edge [loop right] node {} (P2);
    %%%%%%%%%%
    %%% RECTANGLES %%%
    \node[draw, thick, dotted, rounded corners, inner xsep=3.5em, inner ysep=1em, fit=(P1) (P2)] (box) {};
    \node[fill=white] at (box.south) {\tiny\textbf{\textsc{States}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT n°2 : inclusion of heartbeat shape and `\resizebox`**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\tikzset{
    img/.style={circle, fill=red!40!brown!65,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},
}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %nodes for latent state
    \path[img] (0,7) circle (5mm) [path picture={\node[text width=1cm,align=center,anchor=center,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (P1) at (path picture bounding box.center) {\resizebox{1cm}{!}{\faHeartbeat}};}] ;
    \path[img] (2.5,7) circle (5mm) [path picture={\node[text width=1cm,align=center,anchor=center,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (P2) at (path picture bounding box.center) {\resizebox{1cm}{!}{\tikz{\cat}}};}] ;
    \node[below=5mm of P1.center] (P1l) {\tiny\textbf{\textsc{Low}}};
    \node[below=5mm of P2.center] (P2l) {\tiny\textbf{\textsc{High}}};
    %links
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (P2) edge [bend right] coordinate [pos=0.2] (top) (P1)
    (P1) edge [bend right] (P2)
    ;
    \path (P1) edge [loop left] node {} (P1);
    \path (P2) edge [loop right] node {} (P2);
    %%%%%%%%%%
    %%% RECTANGLES %%%
    \node[draw, thick, dotted, rounded corners, inner xsep=3.5em, inner ysep=1em, fit=(P1) (P2)] (box) {};
    \node[fill=white] at (box.south) {\tiny\textbf{\textsc{States}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well it is my code I don't see you added anything to it! I already made this.

Comment: @Dalek Well, before stating that someone trying to help has just copy-pasted your code I suggest you should first read carefully **THEN** make an advised comment

Comment: It is slightly different and I didn't say you copy-pasted my code, I said I was already able to make to this point and my question is not this. I have a problem using figures from this `\usepackage{tikzlings}` package inside the node.

Comment: Dalek, I updated my code, hope this help.

Comment: Thanks it looks awesome. Would you kindly provide an answer about how I can make this heart shape with heart-rate inside as a symbol which I can also call inside nodes of my graph? I will appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A small variation.mostly off-topic of nice [@ BambOo answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569577/importing-an-external-image-on-top-of-a-node-using-tikz#569605) (+1), for fun and exercise. Main differences are in defined styles, which enable to write shorter and more clear code:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % provide also bold small caps fonts
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every edge/.style = {draw,-Straight Barb},
every label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize\bfseries\scshape, % work with newtxtext
                             fill=white,inner ysep=1pt},
               FIT/.style = {draw, densely dotted, rounded corners,
                             inner ysep=1em, fit=#1},
               img/.style = {fill=yellow!50},
state/.style 2 args = {path picture={\node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) at (\ppbb.center)
                                                          {\tikz[scale=0.6] {#2}};}}
                        ]
\def\ppbb{path picture bounding box}
% states
\fill[img] (0,0) circle (6mm) [state={P1}{\penguin[body=teal]}] ;
    \node (p1) [label=below:Low] at (P1.south) {};
\fill[img] (3,0) circle (6mm) [state={P2}{\penguin[body=red]}] ;
    \node (p2) [label=below:High] at (P2.south) {};
% links
\path   (P2) edge [bend right]  (P1) % , coordinate [pos=0.2] (top)
        (P1) edge [bend right]  (P2)
        (P1) edge [loop  left]  coordinate (L)  (P1)
        (P2) edge [loop right]  coordinate (R)  (P2);
    %%%%%%%%%%
% automatom border
\node[FIT=(L) (P1) (p2) (R),
      label={[anchor=center]below:States}]  {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]